# Problem debugging script $(this).find is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem debugging this script, the initial problem was “$().ready is not a function” so I wrapped this part of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
    $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

Up like so

```
 ( function($) { 
  $(document).ready( function() { 

  $('#menu-main-nav > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
  $('#menu-main-nav > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);
   });

  document.onclick = jsddm_close;

 } ) ( jQuery );
```

But I now get a $(this).find is not a function on the line "jsddm_close();" - any help appreciated, I'm sure it's something simple. Full script as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeout         = 500;
    var closetimer      = 0;
    var ddmenuitem      = 0;

    function jsddm_open()
    {   jsddm_canceltimer();
        jsddm_close();
        ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}

    function jsddm_close()
    {   if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

    function jsddm_timer()
    {   closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

    function jsddm_canceltimer()
    {   if(closetimer)
        {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
            closetimer = null;}}

    ( function($) {

            $(document).ready( function() { 

            $('#menu-main-nav > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
    $('#menu-main-nav > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);

    });

    document.onclick = jsddm_close;

    } ) ( jQuery ); 

</script>
```

Comment: why don't you wrap all of your javascript into that anonymous function ? That way you have a guaranteed reference to `jQuery` via `$` **plus** you don't clobber the global object.

Comment: What are you seeing in Firebug? Same error?

Comment: There is problem in that js code is messed with jQuery. Change `document.onclick = jsddm_close;` to `$(document).click(function(){jsddm_close(this);});` and receive `this` as argument in `jsddm_close`

Comment: But @kradmiy though I agree with you, that "jsddm_close" function doesn't itself refer to "$(this)" ...

Comment: I'm still trying to find line 74

Comment: @Josh - sorry line 74 is jsddm_close();

Comment: @Jakub Firebug outputs as follows $(this).find is not a function
jsddm_open()
handle(a=Object { originalEvent=, type="mouseover", more...})
a = Object { originalEvent=, type="mouseover", more...}
add()
[Break On This Error] ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be wrappin' up e'erbody in an anonymous function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {

    var timeout         = 500;
    var closetimer      = 0;
    var ddmenuitem      = 0;

    function jsddm_open() {   
        jsddm_canceltimer();
        jsddm_close();
        ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    function jsddm_close() {   
        if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

    function jsddm_timer() {   
        closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);
    }

    function jsddm_canceltimer() {   
        if (closetimer) {   
            window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
            closetimer = null;
        }
    }


    $(document).ready( function() { 
        $('#menu-main-nav > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open);
        $('#menu-main-nav > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer);
    });

    document.onclick = jsddm_close;

})(jQuery)

</script>
```

Comment: That's great Chris, thank you - forgive the n00b question but why was my solution incorrect?